# R package will be published in corresponding CRAN directory?

Tags: r, cran

I recently submitted my 2nd R package "FMC" to CRAN.
They accepted its publication but told me "**Your package FMC_1.0.0.tar.gz has been built for Windows and will be published within 24 hours in the corresponding CRAN directory**".

BUt this was not the case for my 1st R package minimalRSD few weeks ago.

I wanna know:
1. How could I develop packages supported to all platforms by using R-Studio (Windows) ?
2. Does it mean packages built for Windows can not be used in other OS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Please Read How to Ask on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have received the automatic email from CRAN that is sent when your package is built into a Windows binary. This is nothing to think more than a half-second about.

Both of your packages - [FMC](https://cran.r-project.org/package=FMC) and [minimalRSD](https://cran.r-project.org/package=minimalRSD) - have built Windows and Mac OS binaries (as you can see on their respective package description pages at those links).

If your packages do not have compiled code (which yours do not), then there is basically no reason why they wouldn't be *built* for all platforms. (Whether they *work* on all platforms may, of course, be a different story.)

In sum, you probably missed the equivalent email for your first package and there is nothing you have to do.